# How to get out of the DBAN's end-screen advertisement?

Tags: advertisements, dban

DBAN version 2.3.0 (downloaded from [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dban/files/dban/dban-2.3.0/dban-2.3.0_i586.iso/download)) displays a businesses-card-like advert for the company which acquired this software in 2012 -- when DBAN has finished a disk wipe, the program gives no other options than pressing <kbd>0</kbd> to proceed as far as I can tell and then immediately brings up this seemingly permanent ad-screen. No standard keys and key combinations worked: I tried <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, all the function and some modifier keys. To make matters worse, pressing the PC power button doesn't shut down the computer and holding down to hard reset was necessary (I tried on two occasions).

Comment: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>?

Comment: @spikey_richie Alt+F4 worked and opened a console, but a hard reset was still a necessity (if someone knew a shutdown command...) -- please post an answer.

Comment: if you want a shutdown command, use `shutdown /s /t 0` on an elevated command line, which will commence an immediate shutdown. Change `/s` to `/r` to initiate a restart.

Comment: @spikey_richie I see, I verify if I can elevate with `sudo` within DBAN.